# Is a VPN just a proxy which encryts data to the vpn server?

Tags: vpn, proxy

I have trouble understanding the concept of a VPN in contrast to a proxy.

Is it true, that the VPN just encrypts the data which is send from the client to the vpn server and "rest" behaves like a normal proxy?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

A virtual private network is an encrypted connection that serves as a virtual link. It is called a *tunnel* because the 'inner' user network packets are (again) encapsulated in 'outer' transport packets that run between the tunnel ends. The inner packets emerge at the far tunnel end exactly as they've entered it. They see the arbitrarily long outer VPN path as a single hop, and 'tunnel' through it.

Depending on the exact configuration, VPN links belong to the network layer or data link layer. A proxy is an entirely different construct, which serves requests in place for remote destinations at the application layer, which is off topic here.

Both techniques *may* be used for similar purposes, but technically they're very different.

Comment: Can a website detect, whether you use a proxy or a vpn, but not by the means of checking, whether these ip's are from certain providers?

Comment: Some proxies insert headers into the request and are very easy to identify. But unless that happends, the only way of detecting such a connection is because it comes from a well-known IP address.